# Firebase updating the children by replacing previous data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database structure

[image]

when i updated the size from server app then some the data is overwritten
below is the image of Firebase structure after updating size of stock 1

[image: Firebase Database structure after update]

Below is the code where the server app is updating the size or addon in firebase

```
private void saveData() {
    if (foodEditPosition != -1) {
        Common.categorySelected.getFoods().set(foodEditPosition, Common.SelectedFood); //Save Food to Category

        Map<String, Object> updateData = new HashMap<>();
        updateData.put("foods", Common.SelectedFood);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Common.CATEGORY_REF)
                .child(Common.categorySelected.getMenu_id())
                .updateChildren(updateData)
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Reloaded Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        needSave = false;
                        edtPrice.setText("0");
                        edtName.setText("");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to compare those screenshots. First one is showing a node `Brands` and second one is showing `Category`. So its difficult to understand what is getting deleted or overwritten?

Comment: sorry for that let me show the right one

Comment: i have added the right pic now

Comment: Are you talking about those nodes named 0, 1, 2, 3.. getting deleted?

Comment: yes! exactly that is what i'm asking

Comment: Can you try using `setValue()` instead of `updateChildren()` ?

Comment: i didn't, let me give it a try

Comment: still having the same problem

Comment: Is there any variable which contains a NULL value??

Comment: Nop, no variable is null

Comment: I'm not sure of `Common` you using... Do you have getters and setters as well? In a different Java class?

Comment: yes i have added the getters and setters for each java class

Comment: i got the solution, thanks for your help

Comment: on the line updateData.put("foods",Common.selectedFood)  i have changed it to common.categorySelected.getFoods()

Comment: Maybe that was the reason something was null? Anyways glad you got it :-)

Comment: Actually i was only passing out the data which i have updated, right now i have changed it and pass on all the nodes as well with that node which is updated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i haven't tested your code but it seems like you're using `updateChildren()` which has the effect to update child node at the path referred by the keys of the map see the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference). here 1 , 2 , 3 are children of "foods" hence by updating it with the value `Common.SelectedFood` 1 , 2 , 3 are going to be deleted, you can either do `updateData.put("foods/1", Common.SelectedFood);` along with your map to update the food at 1 or remove `.updateChildren(updateData)` and use set value

and the map option is used for simultaneous update here setValue should be ok
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually i was doing the same mistake as you explain.

Comment: cool, i'm glad my answer was useful :)